# How can I Minify a Perl Script?

Tags: perl, minify

I want to minify a perl script so that I can detect practically identical perl scripts that have only differences in line comments, blank lines, etc. I there a pre-built script to do this minification? If so, I would be able to checksum and highlight the identical files on my own.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly minifying, but you can use [`B::Deparse`](https://metacpan.org/module/B::Deparse) to compile a Perl script, then decompile it back to Perl.

You can diff the results.

A simple command line example follows:

```sh
david@Workstation:comp # perl -MO=Deparse 1.pl > a.pl
1.pl syntax OK
david@Workstation:comp # perl -MO=Deparse 2.pl > b.pl
2.pl syntax OK
david@Workstation:comp # diff a.pl b.pl
david@Workstation:comp # diff 1.pl 2.pl
3c3,5
< say "Hello";
---
> 
> 
>   say "Hello";
david@Workstation:comp #
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using the [`perltidy`](https://metacpan.org/module/perltidy) utility to 'standardize' the format across multiple scripts.

It even has an 'obfuscation' flag which is explained in the documentation:

> ### Making a file unreadable
>
> The goal of `perltidy` is to improve the readability of files, but
>   there are two commands which have the opposite effect, `--mangle` and
>   `--extrude`. They are actually merely aliases for combinations of
>   other parameters. Both of these strip all possible whitespace, but
>   leave comments and pod documents, so that they are essentially
>   reversible.
>   ...
>   Note that these options do not provided any meaningful obfuscation, because perltidy can be used to reformat the files.

Answer (score 5):

[Code::CutNPaste](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Code-CutNPaste-0.04/lib/Code/CutNPaste.pm) Find Duplicate Perl Code

```
use Code::CutNPaste;

my $cutnpaste = Code::CutNPaste->new(
    dirs         => [ 'lib', 'path/to/other/lib' ],
    renamed_vars => 1,
    renamed_subs => 1,
);
my $duplicates = $cutnpaste->duplicates;

foreach my $duplicate (@$duplicates) {
    my ( $left, $right ) = ( $duplicate->left, $duplicate->right );
    printf <<'END', $left->file, $left->line, $right->file, $right->line;

Possible duplicate code found
Left:  %s line %d
Right: %s line %d

END
    print $duplicate->report;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides others' answers I would like to suggest you to read Ovid's article on [how to detect duplicate code in Perl](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2012/12/finding-duplicate-code-in-perl.html)? and also
[More on finding duplicate code in Perl](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2012/12/more-on-finding-duplicate-code-in-perl.html).